# pub/static/.htaccess being ignored

Tags: magento2, htaccess

Ive just started working on a Magento 2 site (2.1.9) and trying to add a 301 rewrite to pub/static/.htaccess so that when someone enters an old URL with index.php it removes the index.php with a 301 rewrite.

However when I enter any changes in the htaccess file located in pub/static/, they're being completely ignored...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php     
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Am I missing something? surely I shouldn't have to re-deploy the static files?

Comment: This is because the htaccess you should be modifying is within the root of magento. you can also achieve this using the rewrite manager under the marketing tab

Comment: Thanks thats sorted it

Comment: Glad to hear any other issues don't hesitate to create a new post